# I need a cell to subtract one number from another based on a code word in a third cell

Tags: if-statement, google-sheets

I want a function to subtract one number in a cell from another number on a different page and cell based on what word is in the cell next to the original number.

In the picture is a lista of expenses, so far only groceries is labeled, but the rest will be labeled with car loan, gasoline, clothes, and miscellaneous.

I need a function that will take my budgeted number (like 155 on the right), and compare it to all the words in column H. If a word like “gasoline” is found I want the function to subtract the value to the left of the key word.

[image: 0]

New picture with updated progress

=ARRAYFORMULA(IF(H2:H="Groceries", J2:J-G2:G, ))

This code is making all of I return what subtracting any number with “Groceries” next to it by the value in its respective J cell. I only need I2 to change when a new “Groceries” key word is entered, and the value in its respective H cell should be subtracted from the J2 cell.

(https://i.stack.imgur.com/5ar6d.png)

Comment: Should I share as a pdf? I’m on mobile at my nursing job. No computer for a week.

Comment: Updated with the best picture I could provide.

Answer (score 0):

try like this in **`I2`** if it fits

```
=IF(H2="Groceries"; G2-J2; )
```

then you could enter the next level with using an array formula in **`I2`**

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(IF(H2:H="Groceries"; G2:G-J2:J; ))
```

for more words use regex like:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(IF(REGEXMATCH(LOWER(H2:H); 
 "groceries|car loan|gasoline|clothes|miscellaneous"); G2:G-J2:J; ))
```

Comment: I clarified my question.

Comment: Thank you so much. I’m at work at the moment, but this looks like it should work or get me close.

Comment: Okay, that worked well, but I’m missing one thing. I need the number to update every time there’s a key word in the H field. I also had to flip J2-G2:G to get a positive number. I removed the other key words and left Groceries, and now I need the number to update when I add another Groceries key word.